# Creating descriptive statistics and print them into word

Tags: r

I would like to generate a descriptive statistic by subgroup (gender of hh head) in R that is than printed into a word document.

I tried to use gtsummary but ended up not really understanding how it works. One problem that occured was that the statistics were not summarised above all surveyed households. The table rather showed each household individually.

```
structure(list(HHID = c("000a1b48-1223-4e6c-8d67-6a1c73f8b433", 
"00147ada-cbd4-4bc9-8b65-b07ec403cf7e", "00165d72-086b-4490-9d5d-82446d9a652f", 
"002552a4-59d7-4244-bc7f-f749e056d442", "00334d35-5375-4689-b39e-f000ec097d08", 
"005c8a23-00f7-4a13-a7fa-b991fd597b2e"), computer = c(1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), bulb = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), charger = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1), radio = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tv = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), 
    fan = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), fridge = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L), therm_app = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), mech_app = c(1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), high_edu_male = c(17, 15, 12, 14, 16, 
    16), numhh_mem_young = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 2L), hours_grid = c(NA, 
    3L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 4L), gen_head = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), high_edu_female     = c(16, 9, 10, 12, 16, 12), dec_expensive = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
    dec_clothes = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), dec_market = c(1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0), dec_dur = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), dec_stove = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1), num_chairs = c(6L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 4L), num_bic = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), num_motorbi = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L), num_car = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), hh_expen = c(20000L, 
    5000L, 8000L, 15000L, 15000L, 15000L), own_home = c(0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1), hhmem_room = c(1, 1.33333333333333, 1.16666666666667, 
    0.625, 1.5, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the command I tried:

```
as_tibble(all_summary)
all_summary %>% tbl_summary(by = gen_head)
print(all_summary)
```

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and expected output. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. [Do not post images of code and/or data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6382434).

Comment: I think this question should be re-opened since you have made edits to improve the quality of your question. Is `all_summary` the `dput` output in your post? Or were there intermediate steps you took to try and create it? If the latter, please add those steps.

Comment: I agree that more information about the data and what you want your final table to look like would be helpful.

Comment: You may like to try the `table1` package. For example something like `table1(~ fan + fridge + therm_app + num_chairs | gen_head, data = df)` could be along the lines of what you are after.

Comment: Thank you! `all_summary` is the data frame I want to use to get the summary statistics. I would like to have summary statistics from all of the variables but by the gender of the household head `gen_head`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It actually worked!! Is there any way to extract this table into a word document? And do you know if there is a way to alter the table and display some of the values in percent?